# Error executing selenium scripts through maven

Tags: maven, selenium

I am getting the following error when executing 'install' command for maven

```
**[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com.amazon.hybrid ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to G:\My Learnings\Framework\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------**
**[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error**
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.483s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 22 23:27:00 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project com.amazon.hybrid: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Below is my pom.xml structure

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.amazon.hybrid</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.amazon.hybrid</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>This is used to order items from Amazon.in</description>


  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>

  <plugins>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>

        <configuration>
            <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>            
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>

        <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>         
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>

    </plugin>

  </plugins>

  </build>

</project>
```

Note:

I have changed the environment from JRE to JDK by Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Added JDK and selected JDK
2. Updated Project

Even after doing the previous steps, the issue remains unresolved.

Any help in solving the issue is appreciated.

Regards,
ANUP J

Comment: What is your JDK version please? Can't believe it's JDK 2 ^^ I guess you need JDK 7 or 8.

Answer (score 0):

You are using very old versions of almost everything present in your pom.xml
you can download the latest versions from here **--->** [Maven repository link to get latest dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/)

I'm mentioning few of them :

**Selenium**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**TestNG**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Similarly, you can find rest of the dependencies from the above given link.

Let me know if it helps. :)

Comment: Hi Anuj, thanks for the response.. i tried the solution but I believe there are compatibility issues with latest version of selenium  and firefox versions. In addition to that firefox doesnt support latest gecko driver too.. and hence i was using the "Selenium 2' version to avoid these compatibility issues

Comment: The issue I,m facing, is it because of the versions ?

Comment: It could be , but I'm also using the latest version of firefox with latest version of gecko driver and selenium and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks Anuj,  I tried the following versions.. Firefox - 46, Selenium 3.4.0, testng 6.11, geckodriver 0.17, I faced **"org.openqa.selenium.invalidargumentexception missing type parameter"** so i switched back to the version without geckodriver.